# Firefox Webdriver NuGet dependency for Linux machine

Tags: firefox, dotnet

I need a Firefox Webdriver which can work on a Linux machine and right now the one that exists in the Nuget repository works only on Windows and I would like to know if there is a way to get one that works in Linux -- if one exists!

The command below installs jbranda's version of the Marionette Driver for Firefox on Windows Machines.

`dotnet add package Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver --version 0.20.0`

I want a similar package for Ubuntu or Linux.

*Is there one such package available?*